# How can I use appium to go through the Activities of an Android app automatically as many as possible?

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium

How can I use appium (or other tools) to go through the Activities of an Android app automatically as many as possible? I have a bunch of Android samples which need to be tested completely. Is there any open source projects I can rely on? Given an arbitrary app, simulate the human operations, fill in the EditText components with random strings, tap all the Buttons, TextView or other clickable components. Once reached the end, it goes back and operates the remained components, pretty much like Depth Search First.

Comment: What does it mean "tap all the buttons". It does not make sense to me.

Comment: you need to find out framework on git and need to add all test cases you want to be tested.